# how to hide Default blank default value in dropdown list when changed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am loading the options in dropdown from the Database through ng-options.i have set a Default Blank value to that dropdown using option.When we change he option ,the default blank value should be hidden and should not be available to select again.It's working in Google Chrome but not in IE9 and 10....

```
<p>
                    Reason<b>*</b>
                </p>
                <p>

                    <select data-ng-model="prvdNote.prvdReason" data-ng-options="option as option.value for option in reasons" ng-class="{showHighlight:validationError.isReason}" ng-disabled="isDisabled"><option
                            style="display: none" >Select Reason</option></select>


                </p>
```

In the Above Code "Select Reason" is Disapperaing when we change the option In Google Chrome,but when we Run it in IE9 its not Disappearing and but I am able to disable that blank value by disabled="disabled".But it should Disappear on changing the option,How can we do this,please help

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="select" data-ng-model="prvdNote.prvdReason" data-ng-options="option as option.value for option in reasons" ng-class="{showHighlight:validationError.isReason}" ng-disabled="isDisabled"><option
                            value="" >Select Reason</option><option
                            value="2" >2</option><option
                            value="3" >3</option></select>

$('#select').on("change",function() {
  if($(this).val()!="") {
    $('#select').find('option[value=""]').remove();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngk0dvja/

Comment: I don't know jquery actually,I want to write it in AngularJs or javascript.Can u please guide me with that